# PutImageData gives black screen

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, putimagedata

I have an array of pixel data that is passed from a webgl program. I then process the pixel data for green screening and output the result into a 2d canvas. Considering I am new with Canvas 2d my question is, how do I properly pass image data to the canvas.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var SetCanvas = function(data){
    var id = ctx.createImageData(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    id.data = data;
    ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
};
```

Comment: If the canvas is empty, then any images made of it will be black...

Comment: This is my first time using the 2d context of canvas, so what exactly does a canvas being empty mean? And how do I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` property of the ImageData object can't be set like that.

You need to set every values of this Uint8ClampedArray to the ones of your incoming `data`.

If `data` is an ArrayLike object and holds Uint8Clamped values, then you can use the [`set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set) method of TypedArrays.

```
var SetCanvas = function(data){
  var id = ctx.createImageData(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  id.data.set( data );
  ctx.putImageData(id, 0, 0);
};
```

But of course this assumes `data` holds correct data (that is 4 rgba Uint8 values per pixels, and with a length of *innerWidth x innerHeight x 4*).

Also, you were puting your input `data` instead of the ImageData `id`.